# Index.php process causing CPU Max Usage

Tags: magento2

I recently had my website moved to a new server. After a day my CPU is maxed out. There are not any errors in my logs and my cache is running. When I check the processes I see that the same command has ran multiple times and is taking up all the resources. What would cause this and how do I solve/debug the issue?

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
buyglas1  587780  0.1  0.0 382708 17612 ?        S    09:31   0:04 lsphp
buyglas1  591422 11.8  0.2 492944 91408 ?        Rs   10:03   1:16 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592033 11.6  0.2 500096 98032 ?        Rs   10:09   0:31 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592036 12.0  0.2 420052 84956 ?        Rs   10:09   0:31 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592054  0.0  0.0  11828  3860 pts/2    S    10:09   0:00 /bin/bash -l
buyglas1  592282 11.9  0.2 420028 83120 ?        Rs   10:10   0:27 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592285 11.8  0.2 498944 95000 ?        Rs   10:10   0:26 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592288 11.9  0.2 420028 83132 ?        Rs   10:10   0:25 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592311  0.0  0.0   6720   744 pts/2    T    10:10   0:00 less
buyglas1  592356 11.8  0.2 420028 83132 ?        Rs   10:11   0:20 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592368 11.7  0.2 416212 79904 ?        Rs   10:11   0:17 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592375 11.4  0.2 494408 90660 ?        Rs   10:11   0:17 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592380 11.6  0.2 420028 82820 ?        Rs   10:11   0:16 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592412 11.3  0.3 502084 99284 ?        Rs   10:12   0:11 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592413 11.4  0.2 417992 81072 ?        Rs   10:12   0:11 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592432 11.6  0.2 422076 84856 ?        Rs   10:12   0:08 lsphp:/home/USERNAME/public_html/index.php
buyglas1  592519  0.0  0.0  49840  1644 pts/2    R+   10:14   0:00 ps -aux
```

**Update**
I've found that there is a cron job that is running into this error

```
General error: 1525 Incorrect DATETIME value: 'NULL', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `cms_block` AS `main_table` WHERE (`valid_from` != 'NULL') AND (`valid_to` != 'NULL'). Statistics: {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":176422912,"emalloc_start":174038040}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `valid_from` and `valid_to` columns in cms_block.  Are they added by an extension?

Comment: I believe this issue has to do with recently moving to MySQL 8. We are still working on the issue